# Reloading authorities for all currently logged in users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm logged as "super admin" and I've changed authorities for one specific user group. In this user group there are currently logged in users with active session.
How can I reload all logged in users authorities without logging them out?

I'm storing all the active session IDs in database, then on "reload authorities" I fetch them and pass to this method:

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

private void refreshSessionWithNewAuthorities(Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, String sessionId) {
    SessionInformation sessionInformation = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId);
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User principal = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) sessionInformation.getPrincipal();

    sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(sessionId, principal);
    sessionInformation.refreshLastRequest();
}
```

Any ideas how can I refresh authorities for all specific sessionid?

The following code example for reloading request "owner", is there a way to obtain the Authentication object for any active session?

```
private void refreshSessionWithNewAuthorities(Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    Authentication currentAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(currentAuth.getPrincipal(), currentAuth.getCredentials(), authorities);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to do this? It's very common that a user needs to re login after a permission change. Even with Windows.

Comment: @HerrDerb there was a team meeting and we agreed to this solution. Maybe, if nothing comes up, I'll try to convince them to log out users with some message.

Comment: This definitely would be my first choice. Otherwise, your making life unnecessary complicated. What kind of application are you building?

Comment: Forest industry, lots of maps and forest administration.

Comment: Are we talking about a Cloud application? Wouldn't it be a nicer solution to push a notification to the client that his permissions have changed, and to make them effective he needs to login in again? This way he also notices the change. If you just refreshing the context whit the new permissions there will be 100% sure the "Did you change my permissions already?" question, because the user doesn't get notified

Comment: No, classic API-based webapp

Answer (score 4):

Instead of painfully try to update all existing user context with new permissions, let them logout and login again.

When changing a users permission, you can check if he currently has an active session an push a notification to the client. This way he will be actively notified about a permission change and that he's got more power now. This most probably will produce a positive experience for the user, compared to a secret change of permissions in the background. <strike>And I am pretty sure he does not bother to log out and login, because this will give him the feeling that he can activate the new permissions himself.</strike>

**Conclusion:**
It's easier for you and a better experience for the user.